# How to deal with middleware setup and configuration questions?

Tags: discussion, comments, scope

I am following [solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solr) rather extensively. As such I am faced often with questions about the basic setup of a Solr server or how certain features need to be configured for it, like the dataimport handler. This would always result in an answer like

- go to the wiki, read the basic setup page
- go to the wiki, read the "How to setup feature xyz" page
- download the example project, check how it is done there
- read the reference manual about this topic

What honestly bugs me about this is that the documentation of Solr is good. There is an openly maintained reference manual that you just need to read. You can even search in it. Mostly those guys just lack the proper wording to find it with Google.

I used to leave a comment and give them directions to the wiki or reference.

What I then observe is a response like

> No, it still does not work.

So I started to flag these question as offtopic, because of asking  us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.

But should I leave a comment with proper directions at all? Mostly it does not help them, but I feel like being rude when not giving a proper comment. And since the question is flagged any-ways, it will get closed and not be findable via Google, helping others. So the effort is wasted.

Moreover those guys would really need a consultant or seminar to get them going with the middleware they want to use. They should not be asking in a programming-centric Q&A page.

I write middleware now, not Solr, since I am rather sure that those things happen also with other middleware components like MySQL, Elasticsearch, etc.

So finally my question is: Should I answer questions about the setup and configuration of middleware questions at all? As long as they do not mention the programming APIs with which you can communicate or embed these middleware, it would be offtopic. Or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solr is not a programming tool; it's a search engine.

Questions about Solr are going to be off-topic on Stack Overflow, unless they have to do with programming the Lucene Java search library and its associated code or programming Solr using actual code.  Questions about Solr setup and installation are clearly off-topic, unless there's some coding basis like installation scripts.

The "recommendations" close reason is the wrong close reason to use for this.  Use the "General Computing Hardware and Software" close reason.

Configuration might be a different matter.   I can see how folks might need help with all that  JSON and XML, and while those are not exactly programming languages, we do answer questions about JSON and XML on a regular basis.

Comment: The lines between configuration and programming can be blurry…

Answer (score 2):

I use the following rule:

1. If its about installation or a "how to" = General Computing and Software
2. If its about "configuration after installation" = General Computing and Software. A popular question here is the kind that "mysql user won't connect".
3. If its about "scripting the install process",  this *might* be on topic. The question content has to be about the scripting part, and not the install part.  So someone asking about a question on a Puppet/Chef script that is giving them an error when trying to install something, this is perfectly on-topic because its about Puppet/Chef and not really about the installation part.

In your case, it falls under #1 for me, so I would have pushed it to General Computing.  It is not really asking for a recommendation, because the person already decided what they want to use.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of the close reason. I got that wrong up to now